# TCPv6 RST sent | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:246

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, dmesg

Am having a strange issue with my AWS Linux Box, since some time am having some up dans down with the sites am hosting.

Randomly for a few mins, the sites are unavailable.

In the dmesg log I find the following messages:

```
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 05:51:46 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCPv6 RST sent | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:246
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:07:54 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCP RST seq_local:3785211806 ack_local:1386283443 seq_remote:1386284927 ack_remote: 3785211806 | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:216
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:07:54 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCPv6 RST sent | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:246
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:30:38 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCP RST seq_local:1618713829 ack_local:2938400610 seq_remote:2938401115 ack_remote: 1618713829 | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:216
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:30:38 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCPv6 RST sent | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:246
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:30:38 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCP RST seq_local:3750800013 ack_local:4037773702 seq_remote:4037774228 ack_remote: 3750800013 | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:216
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:30:38 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCPv6 RST sent | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:246
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:32:21 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCP RST seq_local:3214567008 ack_local:3717613945 seq_remote:3717614470 ack_remote: 3214567008 | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:216
[Mon 07 Nov 2016 06:32:21 AM EST] net.module/1  | TCPv6 RST sent | drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c:2
```

What is going wrong with the system? Is it normal?

Comment: Could be an ack-based DOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the latest Linux source for the file mentioned in your log (`drivers/common/payload2/tb_tcpv6_conn.c`). But there is no `common` subdirectory in the `drivers` directory.

When searching online for the file path I found exactly two hits: Your question and [one other page](https://malwr.com/analysis/ZGM4Yjg4ZTExZGYwNDM5YTk1NzcxMzQ5YmNjZTdmNzM/). On that other page the full path is given as `c:\deepsecurity_dsa\9.0-sp1-p2hf\win32\en\source\src\dsa\drivers\common\payload2\tb_tcpv6_conn.c`

That sounds a lot like the error message originated from a Windows driver.

That begs the question why a message from a Windows driver would show up in the kernel log on a Linux system.

There exists a framework for using Windows network interface drivers on Linux. In my experience that does not work well and should be avoided. So if that is indeed the explanation for the message showing up, my recommendation is to find a native driver for the network interface.

This answer is based on the limited information I could find about this driver. If the actual contents of the `tb_tcpv6_conn.c` source file was available online it would be possible to provide a better answer. However there is no indication that source file has ever been published.